# Installing an RPM package on a server without any access to the internet

Tags: linux, centos, centos-7, package-management, rpm

I have a minimal CentOS server with no access to the internet. Let's call it **server A**.

My target it to build a shell script file to install a specific version of a local RPM file for an application. Let's say the target application is Apache. The problem is that each RPM has dependencies.

On a different server where there is an access to the internet, which I call it **server B**, I download the package:

```
wget http://repo.okay.com.mx/centos/7/x86_64/release/httpd-2.4.35-5.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Then move it to server A and try installing it:

```
rpm -i httpd-2.4.35-5.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

yum install dependency screenshot:
[image: yum install dependency screenshot]

It has several requirement:

```
rpm -qpR httpd-2.4.35-5.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

browse dependencies screenshot:
[image: browse dependencies screenshot]

I cannot understand some of the requirements:

1- What is `/etc/mime.types`? I do not have such a file. Where can I get it from?

2- Some packages are mentioned multiple times such as

```
systemd-utils
systemd-utils
systemd-utils
```

What does it mean?

3- Some packages have multiple variations. Which of them should I install?
[libc.so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ncvP.png)

4- It seems the list is sorted alphabetically. What is the order of installation?

5- The `dnf repoquery` command also provides a different list. Which one should I follow?

dnf repoquery screenshot:
[image: dnf repoquery screenshot]

6- Isn't there a more automatic way to perform what I am looking for?

Comment: Please do not post images, copy the text and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
# Install Yumdownloader using the following command as root user.

yum install yum-utils

# Once installed, run the following command to download a package, for example httpd.
# To download packages with all dependencies, use --resolve option:

mkdir httpd && cd httpd && yumdownloader --resolve httpd

# it will download httpd with all dependencies into working dir.
```

tested on centos 7 inside docker:

```bash
[root@187dddae557b httpd]# ls
apr-1.4.8-7.el7.x86_64.rpm                   httpd-2.4.6-97.el7.centos.5.x86_64.rpm
apr-util-1.5.2-6.el7.x86_64.rpm              httpd-tools-2.4.6-97.el7.centos.5.x86_64.rpm
centos-logos-70.0.6-3.el7.centos.noarch.rpm  mailcap-2.1.41-2.el7.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: What if the target is a local rpm file? For example, I need to install mysql server? I cannot even run `yumdownloader --enablerepo=mysql80-community  --resolve mysql-community-server`.

Comment: Another solution I found is `yum install --downloadonly` but it does not specify the order of installation.

Comment: @mercury a little confuse about you comment, just run `yum -y install /mysoft/*.rpm` should install normally.

Answer (score 0):

1. in such case will be much easier to create local repo, accessible by the host in question.
2. `dnf` provide bigger list because it show ALL the dependencies, not only missing.
3. if you want to use this way just download with `dnf` the required packages and install them.
4. with `rpm` you see dependent package, for example `apr15`, download it, transfer it, install it and try again to install the main package. When you see only filename you can try with `yum provides /etc/mime.types` to get the package name.